# Winsorization when we run regressions by size group

Tags: outliers, winsorizing

I have a sample that consists of large, medium, and small firms and i want to run a separate regression for each size group. When I winsorize a variable should I do it for the whole sample (i.e. select the variable in the whole sample) or for each size group alone (i.e select the large firm subsample and winsorize it for the subsample)?

Comment: Why separate regressions? I'd probably winsorize once overall and run a single regression with interactions of size indicators and your variables?